# DNS & Web Application Deployment

Tags: apache, tomcat, dns, vps

Hi I have the following situation :

Currently on one VPS Box (with 1 IP Address), I have LAMPP running the 'commercial' part of the website on port 80. I then have the actual web application running on Tomcat on port 8080.

I wanted to find out what approach I should take so that people can simply go to www.example.com  (lampp commercial site) or
www.example.com/app/ (web app)   without having to go to www.example.com:8080/app/

How would I go about doing this in DNS and is this even possible at all?

The reason I require LAMPP is because I use PHP for the commercial site, but Java EE for the actual web application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with Apache proxying:

```
ProxyPass /app http://www.example.com:8080/app
ProxyPassReverse /app http://www.example.com:8080/app
ProxyRequests Off
```

Now when you make a request to http://www.example.com/app, it will be forwarded to http://www.example.com:8080/app transparently.

Comment: ah thanks so much!  by transparently do you mean the URL browser at the top will still show 'http://www.example.com/app/

as thewhole application uses url's such as http://www.example.com:8080/app/manage/company  etc...

Comment: It is a transparent proxy, so the browser should see http://example.com/app (without the :8080).

Comment: worked like a charm:)  do you think this would cause any complications? is there anything wrong with doing it via this approach or anything...  the behaviour worked perfectly on my machine. Last question - do we need to define every possible URI we have  /app/bookings/  etc...

Comment: @TylerEvans: I don't believe you have to define every possible URI (you'd have to check of course). There's no complications because Apache will restrict all its proxying to that one path.